# How motherboard identify hard disks list?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios, sata

Happy Holidays :) .

Today I bought a new internal hard disk , so now I have two working and connected hard disks at the same time , back then before I bought it , the hard disk was identified as "disk 0" in "Disk Management" , now the new one is "disk 0" and the old is "disk 1" , so how windows get it ?

I mean I made sure to arrange the SATA cables in order so the old gets the first place then the new one then the DVD-ROM , sadly after that bios still treat my old disk as "disk 1" so I played with their position on SATA ports but still the same , so how the motherboard at all arrange 'em ?

Note 1 : I get over it by making my old disk as a first boot option in bios .

Note 2 : those are specs I guess you need 'em guys to help me out.

- Old Disk : 320GB WD BlackCover.
- New Disk : 500GB WD BlueCover.
- Motherboard : Foxconn G31MXP
- BIOS : Phoenix Tech. V6.00

Other specs not needed for this problem I guess.

Comment: Generally it is by port number. Why do you need to have the drives in a specific order though?

Comment: @JMY1000 for the boot sequence .

Comment: Just set the boot sequence independent of where the drives are plugged in? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.